# Efficient way to transform ByteBuffer stream into lines in Rx

Tags: java, nio, reactive-programming, rx-java

I want to transform `Observable<ByteBuffer>` into lines (`Observable<String>`) by splitting by line ending character. If we have functions such like `toString`, `concat` and `splitByLine`, we must be able to do as the following:

```java
Observable<ByteBuffer> o = ...;
o.map(toString).reduce(concat).flatMap(splitByLine);
```

This algorithm, however, needs to scan whole bytes first and store them in the memory before actually emit the first line of deserialized string. How to emit new line each time the line ending appears in the bytes incrementally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found [rxjava-string](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaString). It provides us with *Rx operators* to handle a stream of **chunked** byte arrays and strings. The API document is found [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/String-Observables).

The question can be achieved by the following:

```java
Observable<byte[]> o = ...;
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
// StringObservable have no operators for ByteBuffer yet
StringObservable.byLine(StringObservable.decode(o, charset));
```